# Problem with accessing elements from DOM in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a tree component in react. The children of a node are added in the DOM only after I expand that node. After I expand a node I want to modify some children of that node, but also a request is made and the expanding takes a bit of time, and I need to set a timeout to be able to modify the children. How can I modify the children only after they appear in the DOM?

`

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { 
    setSelectedKeys, 
    setExpandedKeys,
    setDetails
} from "../../../../actions/tree";
import {doPost} from "../../../../helpers/_http";

const NNPButton  = ({ treeType, selectedDb }) => {
    let dispatch = useDispatch();
    let selectedKeys = useSelector(state => state.tree[treeType].selectedKeys);
    const expandedKeys = useSelector(state => state.tree[treeType].expandedKeys);
    const getSubTreeOnDemand = async (org_id) => {
        const posting = await doPost("ajax/getSubTreeOnDemand", {
            db_name: selectedDb,
            db_type: "Global",
            org_id,
        });
        if (posting.status === 200) {
            return posting.data
        }
    }
    const handleNNPClick = async () => {
        if(expandedKeys.indexOf(selectedKeys[0]) === -1) {
            dispatch(setExpandedKeys([...expandedKeys, selectedKeys[0]], treeType));
        }
        let subTreeOrgs = await getSubTreeOnDemand(selectedKeys[0]);
            console.log(subTreeOrgs);
            setTimeout(() => {
                subTreeOrgs.forEach(org => {
                    document.querySelector(`[title='${org.name} (${org.lm_nokia_name})']`).style.backgroundColor = "red";
                })
            }, 200)
    }
    return(
        <button
            className="dbsButtons"
            id="checkOrgRight"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="tooltip"
            data-placement="botton"
            title="Checks org that is clicked on and his direct children if they comply with Nokia Naming Policy!"
            onClick={() => handleNNPClick()}
        >
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
            NNP
        </button>
    );
}

export default NNPBu
```

`

Comment: You probably don't have the right approach. Using react you never want to edit the DOM directly. You'll edit the DOM, but not the react state managing it. React will just erase your changes to match its internal state.Investigate which component is rendering your tree and look which property you can set to match your need.